# how to get the url in the browser as a parameter to the backend in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using MEAN Stack. I am sending the user ID as a url.

```
<div>
 <% users.forEach( function( user ){ %>
   <li><a href=""><%= user.username %></a></li>
   <li><a href="updateEmployee/<%= user._id %>"><%= user.id %></a></li>
 <% }); %>
</div>
```

I want to get this user ID as a parameter in the routes and query the details of the user who has that ID.

> I tried this as following

```
router.get('/updateEmployee/:ID', function (req, res) {

User.findOne({_id: req.ID}, function ( err, users, count ){

  res.render( 'viewUser', {
    users : users
  });
});
```

});

> How I display in ejs

```
 <li><a href="/AdminDatabase/viewUser"><%= users.username %></a></li>
 <li><a href="/AdminDatabase/viewUser"><%= users.id %></a></li>
```

I referred to https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters to write this code.

But I am getting an error saying **Cannot read property 'username' of null**

Am I doing this in the correct way. If yes What is my mistake? Or how can I do this in any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using **_id:req.ID** you should be using **_id:req.params.ID** in your Mongoose findOne function

Comment: Glad it worked! Can you mark as correct answer so it may help others?